# Tensorflow: Writing an Op in Python

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to write an Op in Python. This tutorial only explains how to do it in c++ with a Python wrapper. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html#adding-a-new-op

How can I write it completely in Python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func).

> Wraps a python function and uses it as a tensorflow op.
>
> Given a python function func, which takes numpy arrays as its inputs and returns numpy arrays as its outputs.

---

Your python function needs to have:

- numpy arrays as inputs, fed from the graph with the argument `inp`
- numpy arrays as outputs, you need to specify their types to TensorFlow in the argument `Tout`

Inside the function, you can do whatever you like, if conditions of for loops, anything that is not possible in TensorFlow.

---

However, the operation will be executed on CPU so it may be slower than the equivalent TensorFlow op in GPU.

Comment: How can I execute the operation on GPU? Do I have to implement this GPU version on c++? Is there a way to write the code in Python?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to write the GPU operation in Python. You can always try to open another question with the implementation you have in mind and someone will maybe come up with an idea to implement it directly in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `tf.py_func` to call python functions. The operations inside the function can also be on GPU. For example, we can add an Op and its gradient purely in python which calls Caffe on GPU:

```
def custom_loss_impl(x):
    caffe.set_mode_gpu()
    caffe.set_device(0)
    ...
    return np.float32(loss)

def custom_loss(x):
    tf.RegisterGradient("custom_loss_grad")(custom_loss_grad)
    g=tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc":"custom_loss_grad"}):
        return tf.py_func(custom_loss_impl,[x],[tf.float32])[0]

def custom_loss_grad_impl(x):
    caffe.set_mode_gpu()
    caffe.set_device(0)
    custom_loss_impl(x)
    ...
    return np.float32(gradient)

def custom_loss_grad(op,grad):
    x=op.inputs[0]
    return tf.py_func(custom_loss_grad_impl,[x],[tf.float32])#assume grad=1
```

Comment: With this approach, and assuming the rest of your tensorflow graph is on the GPU, your data will move tensorflow GPU -> CPU -> caffe GPU -> CPU -> tensorflow GPU again.....

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the main reason to write a new Op *without* using C  is that you want to implement a custom gradient.  If that is why you want to make an Op, you can now do that with tf.custom_gradient