# Tensorflow: How to write op with gradient in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

I would like to write a TensorFlow op in python, but I would like it to be differentiable (to be able to compute a gradient).

This question asks how to write an op in python, and the answer suggests using py_func (which has no gradient): [Tensorflow: Writing an Op in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924071/tensorflow-writing-an-op-in-python)

The TF documentation describes how to add an op starting from C++ code only: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html

In my case, I am prototyping so I don't care about whether it runs on GPU, and I don't care about it being usable from anything other than the TF python API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, as mentionned in @Yaroslav's answer, it is possible and the key is the links he references: [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1095) and [here](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342). I want to elaborate on this answer by giving a concret example.

**Modulo opperation:** Let's implement the element-wise modulo operation in tensorflow (it already exists but its gradient is not defined, but for the example we will implement it from scratch).

**Numpy function:** The first step is to define the opperation we want for numpy arrays. The element-wise modulo opperation is already implemented in numpy so it is easy:

```
import numpy as np
def np_mod(x,y):
    return (x % y).astype(np.float32)
```

The reason for the `.astype(np.float32)` is because by default tensorflow takes float32 types and if you give it float64 (the numpy default) it will complain.

**Gradient Function:** Next we need to define the gradient function for our opperation for each input of the opperation as tensorflow function. The function needs to take a very specific form. It need to take the tensorflow representation of the opperation `op` and the gradient of the output `grad` and say how to propagate the gradients. In our case, the gradients of the `mod` opperation are easy, the derivative is 1 with respect to the first argument and 
[image] with respect to the second (almost everywhere, and infinite at a finite number of spots, but let's ignore that, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849280/derivative-of-remainder-function-wrt-denominator for details). So we have

```
def modgrad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0] # the first argument (normally you need those to calculate the gradient, like the gradient of x^2 is 2x. )
    y = op.inputs[1] # the second argument

    return grad * 1, grad * tf.neg(tf.floordiv(x, y)) #the propagated gradient with respect to the first and second argument respectively
```

The grad function needs to return an n-tuple where n is the number of arguments of the operation. Notice that we need to return tensorflow functions of the input.

**Making a TF function with gradients:** As explained in the sources mentioned above, there is a hack to define gradients of a function using `tf.RegisterGradient` [[doc]](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#RegisterGradient) and `tf.Graph.gradient_override_map` [[doc]](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html).

Copying the code from [harpone](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342) we can modify the `tf.py_func` function to make it define the gradient at the same time:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):

    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)
```

The `stateful` option is to tell tensorflow whether the function always gives the same output for the same input (stateful = False) in which case tensorflow can simply the tensorflow graph, this is our case and will probably be the case in most situations.

**Combining it all together:** Now that we have all the pieces, we can combine them all together:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

def tf_mod(x,y, name=None):

    with ops.op_scope([x,y], name, "mod") as name:
        z = py_func(np_mod,
                        [x,y],
                        [tf.float32],
                        name=name,
                        grad=modgrad)  # <-- here's the call to the gradient
        return z[0]
```

`tf.py_func` acts on lists of tensors (and returns a list of tensors), that is why we have `[x,y]` (and return `z[0]`). 
And now we are done. And we can test it.

**Test:**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

    x = tf.constant([0.3,0.7,1.2,1.7])
    y = tf.constant([0.2,0.5,1.0,2.9])
    z = tf_mod(x,y)
    gr = tf.gradients(z, [x,y])
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    print(x.eval(), y.eval(),z.eval(), gr[0].eval(), gr[1].eval())
```

> [ 0.30000001  0.69999999  1.20000005  1.70000005] [ 0.2 0.5 1. 2.9000001] [ 0.10000001  0.19999999  0.20000005  1.70000005] [ 1.  1.  1.  1.] [ -1.  -1.  -1.  0.]

**Success!**

Comment: Thanks a lot for this post! Do you have how to tell Tensorflow the shape of `z`?
`x` has shape (4), `y` has shape (4), but Tensorflow does not know that `z` has shape (4). Only at runtime, it will resolve that the shape is 4.

Comment: `z[0] = tf.reshape(z[0], [int(x.get_shape()[0])])` I used this to enforce it.

Comment: Are you sure your gradients are correct? Thanks!http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849280/derivative-of-remainder-function-wrt-denominator

Comment: @PhilippeRemy, you don't need to tell Tensorflow the shape of `z` it deduces it automatically from `x` and the operator.

Comment: @PhilippeRemy, yes, good point about the gradients, I ignored the gradient with respect to `y` because I didnt care about it for my example, but you are right that that is not correct. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Great answer. Just as a side note, `tf.py_func` cannot be used if you plan to serialize your graph (e.g. to run it in C++ later). In that case, you can still define an op an gradient, but it's just more complicated, since you have to do it in C++. There's a bit more of info in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283357/1782792).

Comment: @patapouf_ai thanks for the great answer. I also need the numpy version of input in the grad function, so I call `op.inputs[0].eval()` in `modgrad`. So my question is that is it possible to implement everything in numpy in grad function as well?

Comment: Ah ok, I should wrap the grad function into `tf.py_func` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of adding gradient to a specific `py_func`
https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342

Here's the issue [discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1095#issuecomment-239406220)

Comment: Thanks, that gist does answer the question.  Mainly it is to call tf.RegisterGradient() and then gradient_override_map().  As they guys at the issue mention that is a terribly hacky way because it relies on giving the function a name, but it seems the only way right now.  Thanks again!