# TensorFlow pass gradient unchaned

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Say I have some custom operation `binarizer` used in a neural network. The operation takes a `Tensor` and constructs a new `Tensor`. I would like to modify that operation such that it is only used in the forward pass. In the backward pass, when gradients are calculated, it should just pass through the gradients reaching it.

More concretly, say `binarizer` is:

```
def binarizer(input):
    prob = tf.truediv(tf.add(1.0, input), 2.0)
    bernoulli = tf.contrib.distributions.Bernoulli(p=prob, dtype=tf.float32)
    return 2 * bernoulli.sample() - 1
```

and I setup my network:

```
# ...

h1_before_my_op = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(x, W) + bias_h1)
h1 = binarizer(h1_before_b)

# ...

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_true))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

How do I tell TensorFlow to skip gradient calculation in the backward pass?

---

I tried defining a custom operation as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984513/482601), however: `py_func` cannot return `Tensor`s, that's not what it is made for – I get:

> UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): Unsupported object type Tensor

Comment: You want your subgraph to behave like `tf.identity` for the backwards pass, so you can use trick here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456436/how-can-i-define-only-the-gradient-for-a-tensorflow-subgraph/36480182#36480182

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Nice! I finally had time to implement this today and it seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`tf.stop_gradient(input, name=None)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/train.html#stop_gradient):

> Stops gradient computation.
>
> When executed in a graph, this op outputs its input tensor as-is.

```
h1 = binarizer(h1_before_b)
h1 = tf.stop_gradient(h1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that this stops gradients rather than passing them on? I.e. that everything to the left of `h1` does not receive gradients in my tests: All weights associated with the stages to the left of `h1` do not get updated by the training step, the ones on the right do...