# How to simulate reduced precision floats in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, rounding, precision

I would like a way to reduce the precision of floats in TensorFlow (approximately: truncate the mantissa) to an arbitrary number of bits within a defined full range.  I don't need to write code entirely in reduced precision (like tf.float16), but rather to come up with a series of operations that reduce the precision of a tensor while leaving it the original type (eg tf.float32).

For example, if the full range is 0 to 1, and the precision is 8 bit, 0.1234 would become round(0.1234 * 256) / 256 = 0.125.  This uses simple rounding.

I would also like to do statistical rounding, where the probability of rounding in each direction is proportional to how far the value is from that.  For example, 0.1234 * 256 = 31.5904, which would round up to 32/256 59% of the time, and to 31/256 41% of the time.

Extra question: How to take an existing graph and modify it to add rounding after every convolution?

Comment: Have you read https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization ?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Yes, I looked at that, it seems like a somewhat different use case. I need arbitrary number of bits, not just 8, and I don't want to convert every op in a graph.

Comment: Okay that was all I could do to help sorry ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tricky part is to provide the gradients to the rounding operation. The already implemented `tf.round` does not have a gradient implemented. But you can implement your own rounding operation (statistical or simple rounding both work) as shown here:
[Tensorflow: How to write op with gradient in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048984/tensorflow-how-to-write-op-with-gradient-in-python/39984513#39984513)

Where you can simply use:

```
grad(round(T)) = round(grad(T))
```

Now once you have your personalized `round` operation which transfers gradients you can simply do:

```
def reduce_precision(tensor, precision_bits=8):
    N = 2**precision_bits
    return round(N * tensor)/N
```

And for the stochastic rounding, you can create a simple numpy function like

```
def stochastic_round(x):
    r,f = np.modf(x)
    return r + np.random.binomial(1,r)
```

and then tensoflow-ize it as shown in [How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/tensorflow-how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python/39921608#39921608)

where you can define it's gradient operation as

```
def grad_stochastic_round(op, grad):
    return stochastic_round(grad)
```

Comment: Cool!  I think in my case grad(round(T)) = round(grad(T)).  Any tips for how to do statistical rounding?

Comment: You can do it with a normal python / numpy function and convert it to tensorflow as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/tensorflow-how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python/39921608#39921608

Comment: the python function itself is very simple since you can do something like 
`def round(x): np.floor(x) + np.random.binomial(1,np.modf(x)[0])`

Comment: and `def grad_round(op, grad): return grad`