# How do you write a custom activation function in python for Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, activation-function

I'm trying to write a custom activation function for use with Keras. I can not write it with tensorflow primitives as it does properly compute the derivative. I followed [How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow) and it works very we in creating a tensorflow function. However, when I tried putting it into Keras as an activation function for the classic MNIST demo. I got errors. I also tried the `tf_spiky` function from the above reference.

Here is the sample code

```
tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf_spiky),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
```

Here's my entire error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-73a57f81db19> in <module>
      3                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf_spiky),
      4                       tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
----> 5                       tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
      6 x=tf.keras.layers.Activation(tf_spiky)
      7 y=tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    472     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    473     try:
--> 474       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    475     finally:
    476       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    106     if layers:
    107       for layer in layers:
--> 108         self.add(layer)
    109 
    110   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    472     self._setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    473     try:
--> 474       method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    475     finally:
    476       self._setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    173       # If the model is being built continuously on top of an input layer:
    174       # refresh its output.
--> 175       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    176       if isinstance(output_tensor, list):
    177         raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    728 
    729         # Check input assumptions set before layer building, e.g. input rank.
--> 730         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    731         if input_list and self._dtype is None:
    732           try:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
   1463         if x.shape.ndims is None:
   1464           raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
-> 1465                            self.name + ' is incompatible with the layer: '
   1466                            'its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a '
   1467                            'defined rank.')

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

From this I gather the last `Dense` layer is unable to get the dimensions of the output after the activation function or something to that. I did see in the tensorflow code that many activation functions register a shape. But either I'm not doing that correctly or I'm going in the wrong direction. But I'm guessing something needs to be done to the tensorflow function to make it an activation function that Keras can use.

I would appreciate any help you can give.

As requested here is the sample codes for `tf_spiky`, it works as described in the above reference. However, once put into Keras I get the errors shown. This is pretty much as shown in the *How to make a custom activation function with only Python in Tensorflow?" stackoverflow article.

```
def spiky(x):
    print(x)
    r = x % 1
    if r <= 0.5:
        return r
    else:
        return 0
def d_spiky(x):
    r = x % 1
    if r <= 0.5:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
np_spiky = np.vectorize(spiky)
np_d_spiky = np.vectorize(d_spiky)

np_d_spiky_32 = lambda x: np_d_spiky(x).astype(np.float32)
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

def tf_d_spiky(x,name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, "d_spiky", [x]) as name:
        y = tf.py_func(np_d_spiky_32,
                        [x],
                        [tf.float32],
                        name=name,
                        stateful=False)
        return y[0]

def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):

    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

def spikygrad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0]

    n_gr = tf_d_spiky(x)
    return grad * n_gr  

np_spiky_32 = lambda x: np_spiky(x).astype(np.float32)

def tf_spiky(x, name=None):

    with tf.name_scope(name, "spiky", [x]) as name:
        y = py_func(np_spiky_32,
                        [x],
                        [tf.float32],
                        name=name,
                        grad=spikygrad)  # <-- here's the call to the gradient
        return y[0]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code for `tf_spiky`.

Comment: As mentioned above, The code for `tf_spiky` was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921607/how-to-make-a-custom-activation-function-with-only-python-in-tensorflow. It's rather lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in this post [Output from TensorFlow `py_func` has unknown rank/shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590431/output-from-tensorflow-py-func-has-unknown-rank-shape)

The easiest fix is to add `y[0].set_shape(x.get_shape())` before the return statement in the definition of `tf_spiky`.

Perhaps someone out there knows how to properly work with tensorflow shape functions. Digging around I found a `unchanged_shape` shape function in `tensorflow.python.framework.common_shapes`, which be appropriate here, but I don't know how to attach it to the `tf_spiky` function. Seems a python decorator is in order here. It would probably be a service to others to explain customizing tensorflow functions with shape functions.