# How do I define a gradient for a custom op working on complex tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

If you have a tensor of complex numbers, tensorflow already has an op to get the magnitudes of those complex numbers ([tf.abs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L206)). Now I want to add a function that calculates the angle of each number. This function is easy to implement using numpy and the gradient is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Derivative).

When it comes to adding custom tensorflow ops based on numpy, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048984/tensorflow-how-to-write-op-with-gradient-in-python/39984513#39984513) seems to be the way to go. However here the input are complex numbers. So my question is, is it possible to use the same approach but work with complex numbers? Just directly copying the approach used in tf.abs is not possible, since it uses c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `tf.arg` will exist soon: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/10643.  If you want something before then, I'd recommend

```
def arg(z):
  return tf.atan2(tf.imag(z), tf.real(z))
```

Comment: Great that they are adding it to Tensorflow itself!

Comment: Here is the link to the Tensorflow documentation on tf.angle: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/angle