# How to create new Tensorflow op from composition of existing Tensorflow ops

Tags: python, tensorflow

I know [how to use tf.py_func to create a new custom op](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048984/tensorflow-how-to-write-op-with-gradient-in-python) that runs on CPU. I also know from the [TF guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) you can create a new op and its gradient in C++

What I am looking for is none of the above. I want to define a custom gradient function for a composition of TF ops. [tf.register_gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RegisterGradient) can be used along with gradient_override_map to define a custom gradient for an existing op, but how do you register a composition of TF ops as a new op in the first place?

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592559/tensorflow-creating-a-copy-of-an-existing-op-with-a-different-gradient-functio#) with no answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456436/how-can-i-define-only-the-gradient-for-a-tensorflow-subgraph/36480182#36480182 then f(x) is your composition of ops.

Comment: I tested the above trick; it works. There are concerns that later TF versions may optimize the g(x) out.

Comment: Only when XLA is enabled, which can be decided when installing from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided three different ways of defining custom gradients in Tensorflow in [this repo](https://github.com/safooray/scratch_pad/).

#### custom_gradient_with_py_func

In this approach we define a tf op using tf.py_func and assign a custom gradient function to it.

```
with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
    return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)
```

#### custom_gradient_with_python:

In this approach we use a workaround to define a custom gradient for a composition of Tensorflow ops. We override the gradient of the identity op.

```
def python_func(x_in, name=None):
    with ops.name_scope(name):
        backward_func = tf.identity(x_in) # We'll later override the gradient of identity to deflect our desired gradient function.
        forward_func = tf.subtract(2 * tf.exp(x_in), x_in) 
        return backward_func + tf.stop_gradient(forward_func - backward_func) 

def my_op(func, inp, grad, name=None, victim_op='Identity'):
    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates.
    rnd_name = 'my_gradient' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))
    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({victim_op: rnd_name}):
        return func(inp, name=name)
```

#### custom_gradient_with_eager:

This approach uses tensorflow.contrib.eager available as of Tensorflow 1.5 to define custom gradients for a composition of tensorflow ops.

```
@tfe.custom_gradient
def python_func(x_in):
    def grad_func(grad):
        return grad * ((2 * tf.exp(x_in)) - 1)

    forward_func = tf.subtract(2 * tf.exp(x_in), x_in)
    return forward_func, grad_func
```

Answer (score 0):

[tfe.custom_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/custom_gradient) is the decorator you want to use

Comment: Does this require activating eager mode? Any side effects? I would appreciate more specific information.

Comment: No side effects and does not require activating eager mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you managed to solve your problem but the names 'op_name' and 'some_name' in above solution would not show on the graph. So you will not be able to use gradient_override_map({"op_name": "SynthGrad"}).

One possible solution: If you have a custom tensorflow op x=f(a,b) in forwardpass but you want that to behave as g(a,b) in backwardpass, you can do something like this:

t=g(a,b) out=t+tf.stop_gradient(f(a,b)-t)

However, you need to define g(a,b) in C++ as a dummy/identity operator with a name. Later, you can use gradient_override_map.